# Determining whether a polynomial is linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having some trouble figuring this out.
I want to determine whether $T: P_2 \rightarrow P_2, T(a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2)= a_1+2a_2x$

is a linear transformation or not.

All I have so far is :

Let  $u = a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2$

Let $v = b_0 + b_1x+b_2x^2$

However the part that I'm troubled with is that on the left hand side we have 3 terms $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ and on the right hand side we only have 2 $(a_1,a_2)$.

How can I move forward from here?

Comment: Are you sure the problem doesn't say $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$? Seems like a potential error.

Comment: apologies, it does say that.

Comment: The derivative is a linear transformation, so I thought that might be the case.  Let us know if you still have an issue after trying the problem now.

Comment: Great. I didn't notice it was a derivative until you mentioned it. But am I on the right track with defining u and v? In order to prove T(u+v)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. What you've done by defining two *arbitrary* polynomials $u,v$ is absolutely correct. I know many students who start by picking two *specific* polynomials, so you've avoided that pitfall. By picking two arbitrary polynomials, you're able to prove the linearity property is true for *all* such polynomials.

Recall that you can break down the condition for the linearity of $T$ into two properties:

1. $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$
2. $T(cu) = c T(u)$, where $c$ is an arbitrary scalar value.

So what you need to do is compute the expression $T(u+v)$ and $T(u) + T(v)$ (using the variables that you have defined), and show that they are equal, and do the same for the second part.

Comment: Right, so what I got was
T(u+v) = $[(a_1+b_1)+(a_2+b_2)] + [2a_2+2b_2]x$

     
then $[(a_1+a_2)+(b_1+b_2)] + [2a_2+2b_2]x$

Is this complete for the first part?

Comment: Sure. As long as you've made a convincing argument why $T(u+v)$ has the same value as $T(u) + T(v)$, I think it's fine.

Comment: Alright thanks. I got the 2nd part as well then.

Answer (score -1):

Let $a_0=0$. A linear transformation $T$ requires that $T(0)=0$. It follows that if we pick $x=0$, the LHS becomes $T(0)$ but the RHS is $a_1\not\equiv 0$, so $T$ is not linear.